# MQTT Client unable to connect to AWS IoT MQTT Broker

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ssl, mqtt

I'm unable to connect my C# code to AWS IoT MQTT Broker, however I'm able to connect using AWS MQTT Client to MQTT broker. I'm using M2MQTT as the MQTT Client in my C# code (https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2Mqtt). Note that .pfx file is created using openSSL using the certificate and private key downloaded from AWS IoT. The certificate is activated and attached to a thing. The rootca.crt is Amazon's root CA.

I keep getting error at `Client.Connect(clientId)`

> {uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException:
>   Exception of type
>   'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException'
>   was thrown.   at
>   uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.SendReceive(Byte[] msgBytes,
>   Int32 timeout)   at
>   uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String
>   username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel,
>   Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean
>   cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)   at
>   uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId)

Below is my code

```
   private const string IotEndpoint = "xxvf6ihlpxlxf6.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com";

        private const int BrokerPort = 8883;

        private const string Topic = "dsfds2MQTT/#";
         var clientCert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin\\XXXX.pfx", "XXX#");

                var caCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin\\rootca.crt");

                // create the client
                var client = new MqttClient(IotEndpoint, BrokerPort, true, caCert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
                //message to publish - could be anything
                var message = "Test message";
                string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                //client naming has to be unique if there was more than one publisher
                client.Connect(clientId);
                //publish to the topic
                client.Publish(Topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
```

I also looked at this link [Getting AuthenticationException when connect M2Mqtt.MqttClient to Mosquitto broker with TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793400/getting-authenticationexception-when-connect-m2mqtt-mqttclient-to-mosquitto-brok/48414980#48414980) and [A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception paho m2mqtt Dot.Net(c#) client SSL/TLS connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993106/a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-paho-m2mqtt-dot-netc-client-ssl-tl?rq=1)
where they fixed the issue by converting .crt to .pfx but in my case its Amazon Root CA , I'm not sure how I can convert to .pfx without private key. This looks like an authentication issue but not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Figured out myself using MQTTFX.Client and logs provided by this client. The issue was with my iOT policies that was restricted to publish messages.

Comment: Same, the policy "Resource" was set to the default which doesn't allow connect. I changed it to * and it worked:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}